What are the spaces whose linear operators admit eigen"vectors"?
I know that linear operators over $n$-dimensional, $\mathbb{R}-$vector spaces admit $n$ eigenvalues (in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R},  \mathbb{C}$) and eigenvectors. The proof of this is just noticing that eigenvalues are roots of the $n^{th}$ degree characteristic polynomial  of such an operator.
However, in PDEs, we find eigen"functions" for linear operators over function spaces, which are in general infinite-dimensional. But then  we can't think about their characteristic polynomial, so that a theorem on the existence of eigenvalues/vectors, like above, isn't clear to me.
Therefore, I'm wondering if there is any analogue of the above theorem for linear operators on infinite-dimensional spaces. I think this might involve some functional-analytic ideas, which is a field I haven't seen much of but have basic intuitions of, so I'm open to any and all answers really.

It's a long story: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)

In general, an operator on an infinite-dimensional space doesn't have to have any eigenvalues/eigenvectors at all.  In fact, even with fairly strong additional hypotheses this is the case.  For example, the operator $T : L^2([0, 1]) \to L^2([0, 1])$ defined by $T(f(x)) = xf(x)$ is a bounded, linear, self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, but $T(f) = \lambda f$ means $xf(x) = \lambda f(x)$ (almost everywhere), which means $f(x) = 0$ for almost every $x$, so $f = 0$ as an element of $L^2([0, 1])$.
To remedy this, one usually looks at the spectrum of an operator, which is the set of $\lambda$ such that $T - \lambda I$ is non-invertible.  In finite dimensions this is the same as the set of eigenvalues, but in infinite dimensions the spectrum can (and often does) contain many things that are not eigenvalues, because $T - \lambda I$ can be injective while still not being invertible.

Have a look at the nice theory of Sturm-Liouville operators
